# Problem in connection to DBaaS using cx_oracle

Tags: python, oracle, dbaas

I am trying to connect to an external DBaaS I using the following python code

```
import cx_Oracle
ip = 'my_ip'
port = 49407
db = 'my_db_name'
user_name = 'username'
user_pass = 'password'
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user_name, user_pass, f'{ip}:{port}/{db}')
```

And I'm getting the following error

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12569: TNS:packet checksum failure
```

I don't see any reason why this is happening, but I'm a complete beginner in DBaaS, so maybe there is an easy explanation for this.